# iAd and Delegate Prob

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, iad

this is the first time i´m working with iAd. So the Ad is displayed; all fine. But if i´ve understood it right the function

```
didFailToReceiveAdWithError
```

only get´s called if an error occurs, right? But it´s called every time, i can read every time the NSLog-Message "Error". As i said, the ad is displayed properly.

Here´s the code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>
{
ADBannerView *bannerView;   
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)bannerView didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error;

@end
```

and the m-File looks like this

```
#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,570,320,50)];
bannerView.delegate = self;
[bannerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.view addSubview: bannerView];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)bannerView didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{   
NSLog(@"Error");
}
@end
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: And what does say `error`?

Comment: `NSLog("Error received: %@", error);` and go from there.